# Match a string to the numbers 0-9 in python

Tags: python, regex

This is my bash code which I am converting to python:

```
if [[ "$hostname_from_route53" =~ $host[0-9].$env.$domain ]];
```

I want to be able to compare `"$hostname_from_route53"` with `$host[0-9].$env.$domain`.

This might be:

```
server1.prod.aws.<company>.co.uk =~ $server[0-9].prod.aws.<company>.co.uk
server9.dev.aws.<company>.co.uk =~ $server[0-9].dev.aws.<company>.co.uk
```

I'm struggling to work this into python. I feel like it should include `import re` and some kind of `re.compile` but I seem unable to find an equivalent to the bash example above.

Comment: Try making your question without the bash code.

Comment: You have to write regex for matching this string

Comment: @Sнаđошƒаӽ Thank you. I will try to improve next time.

Answer (score 4):

Something like this should get you going

```
import re

hostname_from_route53 = "server1.prod.aws.<company>.co.uk"

host = "server"
env = "prod"
domain = "aws"

pattern = r'^{host}[0-9]\.{env}\.{domain}'

filled_pattern = pattern.format(host=re.escape(host),
                                env=re.escape(env),
                                domain=re.escape(domain))

regex = re.compile(filled_pattern)

if regex.match(hostname_from_route53):
    do_stuff()
```

Note that a hostname like `server12.dev.aws.<company>.co.uk` won't match with the above. To match numbers above `9` you should change `pattern` to the following:

```
pattern = r'^{host}[0-9]+\.{env}\.{domain}'
```

Comment: Nice usage of variables within a `re.compile`! I wasn't aware this was possible.

Comment: You may want to apply `re.escape()` to the variables first to escape metacharacters embedded in them.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a regex like:

```
re.escape(host) + r"[0-9]\." + re.escape(env) + r"\." + re.escape(domain)
```

So for example you can say:

```
import re

host="myhost"
env="dd"
domain="aa"
my_regex = re.escape(host) + r"[0-9]\." + re.escape(env) + r"\." + re.escape(domain)
for var in ["myhost2.dd.aa", "myhost99.dd.aa"]:
    if re.search(my_regex, var):
        print(var, "matched!")
    else:
        print(var, "did not match")
```

Executing it returns:

```
$ python my_match.py 
('myhost2.dd.aa', 'matched!')
('myhost99.dd.aa', 'did not match')
```

Comment: I assume there are cleaner ways to do this. For example, the way Jivan uses `.format()` makes it easier. I also wonder if `re.escape()` can be used all together instead of calling it for every variable.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst waiting for replies here, I think I cracked it:

```
if re.search(r"%s[0-9].%s.%s" % (host, env, domain), 
               hostname_from_route53, re.IGNORECASE):
```

Comment: There is nothing to excuse from. You presented a clear question (you could have shown some Python code, though, at least your attempts) and then came up with a solution whilst waiting for replies. I like this answer and also do like Jivan's.

Comment: You may want to escape the dots (to only match a literal `.`, not just *any* character), and escape the `host`, `env` and `domain` values too, in case they contain regex meta characters:  `r"%s[0-9]\.%s\.%s" % map(re.escape, (host, env, domain))`